# How to get and plot confidence bands for a FindDistribution fit

Tags: fitting, distributions

`NonlinearModelFit` gave a bad fit to this data, but `FindDistribution` gave a good fit. This code does the fit and shows the results:

```
data= {0.0228278, 0.0235875, 0.0258227, 0.0281474, 0.0299132, 0.0300756, 
0.0301485, 0.0302263, 0.0306889, 0.030902, 0.0330661, 0.0357966, 
0.0361814, 0.0376612, 0.0402447, 0.0429684, 0.0442914, 0.0483349, 
0.0518819, 0.0529263, 0.0545642, 0.056154, 0.0591044, 0.0621301, 
0.0623543};
FindDistribution[data, 10, All, TargetFunctions -> "Continuous"]
Show[Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", Frame -> True], 
Plot[PDF[LogNormalDistribution[-3.266, 0.3239], x], {x, 0, 0.1}, 
PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]]
```

Now I want to add 60% upper and lower confidence bands to the figure. How can this be done?

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit` is for regression and `FindDistribution` is for estimating distributions from a random sample.

Comment: There's an example in the `Applications -> Confidence Intervals` section of the `PDF` docs which might be useful.

Comment: Would NonlinearModelFit with the same distribution as the fit function give the same result as FindDistribution?

Comment: What you have is a random sample from some probability distribution and you want to estimate a probability density function.  That is a totally different situation than performing a regression on data points that just happen to have the shape of a probability density function.  Your choice of "60%" is also way out of the ordinary which suggests to me - and maybe wrongly - that you really ought to talk to a statistician.

Comment: I don't know any statisticians, but will try to find one. In the meantime, can you please elaborate on your comment? E.G., what is an ordinary  confidence band?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval.  While there is no law that says what level of confidence one should choose, if you're deviating from 95%, one should justify why that might be the case.  And as you might imagine choosing a lower level of confidence because the width of the confidence interval is smaller is not a good rationale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, you can do bootstrap to get quick-and-dirty point estimates for standard deviation of `PDF[dist, x]`:

```
edist = EstimatedDistribution[data, LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ]];
bootstrap = PDF[EstimatedDistribution[#, LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ]], x] & /@ 
   RandomChoice[data, {100, IntegerPart[2 Length[data]/3]}];

plt = Plot[{Mean[bootstrap], Mean[bootstrap] - 1.96 StandardDeviation[bootstrap], 
    Mean[bootstrap] + 1.96 StandardDeviation[bootstrap]}, 
   {x, 0, 0.1}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 1 -> {3}}, FillingStyle -> Opacity[.5, Yellow]];

Show[Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", Frame -> True], 
 Plot[PDF[edist, x], {x, 0, 0.1}, PlotStyle -> Red], plt,  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Change `1.96` to `Quantile[NormalDistribution[], .6]` to get

[image]

or, using bootstrap quantiles,

```
plt2 = Plot[{Median[bootstrap], Quantile[bootstrap, .40], Quantile[bootstrap, .60]}, 
  {x, 0, 0.1}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 1 -> {3}}, 
   FillingStyle -> Opacity[.5, Pink], PlotPoints -> 200];

Show[Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", Frame -> True], 
 Plot[PDF[edist, x], {x, 0, 0.1}, PlotStyle -> Red], plt2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I am unaware of "bootstrap," can you please give me some references? Also, does Quantile[NormalDistribution[], .6] give the 60% confidence bands? What does 1.96 give?

Comment: @MichaelB.Heaney, [wikipedia > Bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) and [Efron article](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176344552). Re `1.96` it is `Quantile[NormalDistribution[], .975]` ( the ["z-score"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) for two-sided 95% confidence interval.)